# Python file server

Tags: python

I followed a tutorial to make this, and I'm trying to add an `ls` command so you can see the files to download. The code works, and all the prints return the right things, but the client only shows six letters of one of the files.
Server:

```
import socket
import threading
import os

def RetrFile(name, sock):
    filename = sock.recv(1024)
    if filename != "ls":
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            sock.send("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename)))
            userResponse = sock.recv(1024)
            if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
                    while bytesToSend != "":
                        bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                        sock.send(bytesToSend)
        else:
            sock.send("ERR ")

        sock.close()
    else:
       dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
       retval = os.listdir(dir_path)
       print retval
    for ret in retval:
        print ret
        sock.send(ret)
def Main():
    host = '192.168.0.125'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(5)

    print "Server Started."
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print "client connedted ip:<" + str(addr) + ">"
        t = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("RetrThread", c))
        t.start()

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Directory with the Python file (files to download): [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73gpq.png)

```
Server  Output: "client connedted ip:<('192.168.0.112', 49546)>

['runmeee.exe', 'Untitled.png', 'putty.exe', 'pyserver.py']

runmeee.exe

Untitled.png

putty.exe

pyserver.py"

Client output: runmee
```

Comment: I see the server printing the startup, I see the client printing the result of `os.listdir` and the following loop, but I'm not getting who is sending the commands? And who prints the last `runmee` (buggy) ?

Comment: I fixed the 6 character thing which was because of the client. But, now I just have to make the server combine into one piece of data becuase the client only waits for one

Comment: in that case just do `sock.send("\n".join(retval))` instead of your loop. You'll send 1 file per line in a single text block. Lame serializing but works. Or send `str(retval)` and use `ast.literal_eval` to de-serialize it to a list on the other end.

Comment: Fixed! I just combined into one line of data and I found out the client was printing data[:6] instead of just data.